# Access Denied in /opt

Tags: xubuntu

I've been using Xubuntu 14.04  for 1 month now. I'm trying to install a program "Linuxtrack" - a head tracker for gaming. Their website install instructions state:

> "linuxtrack has to be installed in /opt, otherwise it is not going to
>   work (at least not without changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH to let it find its
>   libraries".

So I opened the Terminal, at the commandline I used **cp -avr** to try and copy the unzipped program file to the /opt directory.

```
hienz1@Kickass:~/Downloads/Linux-Track$ 
cp -avr /home/hienz1/Downloads/Linux-Track/linuxtrack-0.99.17 /opt cp: 
cannot create directory ‘/opt/linuxtrack-0.99.17’: Permission denied
```

Permission Denied? How do I get around this permission denied thing?

:[The "linuxtrack" program wiki is here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/linux-track/wikis/UniversalPkgInstall.wiki)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check permission of directory /opt run:

```
ls -ld /opt
```

output will looks like:

```
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Feb  1 13:34 /opt/
```

As you see this directory is owned by the root user and group root.

More the others permission is r-x which means no write permission is allowed to others(users which are not owner or not in the group). And when you are making a `cp` command this means a writing process inside this dir.

So what you shall do is to use the `sudo` command before your command.

```
sudo cp -avr /home/hienz1/Downloads/Linux-Track/linuxtrack-0.99.17 /opt
```

Comment: @hienz1 Welcome buddy

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `sudo` to achieve this...

```
sudo cp -avr /home/hienz1/Downloads/Linux-Track/linuxtrack-0.99.17 /opt
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Stop geeking around --- Install in `~/opt` --- Move on!

I know this has been answered, but for the future: Let the system install system opts in the system opt dir: `/opt`.  And install your personal opts in your personal opts dir: `~/opt`.  Since you're most likely the only person using your computer it's not worth maintaining a system installation.  Yes you can add yourself to group and let that group own the contents of opt, and you can do all sorts of tricks with setuid and sticky flags but why all the hassle over nothing?